# PDO sql syntax wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have db named `CMS` with two columns: `id` and `data1`

I get following error for the code below when trying to fetch data from the database.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table' at line
>   1' in /var/pdo/index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /var/pdo/index.php(4):
>   PDO->query('SELECT * FROM t...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/pdo/index.php on line 4

Why am I getting this error?

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms;charset=utf8', 'root', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['field1'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't use table as a table name..

Comment: Your database is called CMS. What is the table called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`table` is a reserved word. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html for the full list.

You could use backticks (`` SELECT * FROM `table` ``) if you still want to use your tablename 'table'

Comment: indeed it is: [reserved-words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: beat me by 5 seconds.

Comment: @bart2puck Your answer was better, but because `\`table\`` would work.

Comment: @kelunik forgot to mention that. I've add it to my answer. Thanks for the addition!